# Is comparing (assuming) self with god a sin?

Tags: krishna, gods, sin

Is it allowed to compare god with self. Can I consider myself as Lord Ram, Lord Krishna or is it a sin to compare myself with such gods?

Comment: This is something that different sects of Hinduism differ on.  According to Advaitins, you are Brahman.  According to Madhvas and Gaudiya Vaishnavas, it is a sin to be so arrogant that you consider yourself equal to Vishnu.  According to Sri Vaishnavas, meditating upon yourself as having Brahman as the inner self of your soul is a valid path to Moksha, but you shouldn't think of yourself as equal to Brahman.

Comment: If I compare my self as Krishna and all others too. Then is it a sin? @KeshavSrinivasan

Comment: Like I said, different sects of Hinduism have different views on this.

Comment: Comparing oneself with others is not helpful in spirituality. Comparing means 'Am I great or is He great'. It implies duality. However in Advaita, the person is not comparing himself with God. He is replacing himself with God (or equating himself to God). He does not say "I am God, worship Me". He says "I am God, and so Are You!" or from a more Absolute sense He says "I am God, there is no-one else but Me in this Universe". This is a common misconception about Advaita. Anyway the answer 'comparing' is not a helpful thing. However is it a sin? It's not a sin if you have faith. God loves you.:)

Comment: @Sai you should put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the result of comparison.

You can, and should compare yourself with God.
What is the result of any comparison - better, worse, equal - right ?

So, what is the result of comparing myself with Bhagavan ? If I say 'I am worse. God is better' - it is not sin.

'Bhagavad-Guna, Sva-dosha, Prakatanam Kuru' - Loudly praise lord and denigrate yourself.

This is from Vaishnava Paramparai upanyasam by Velukkudi Krishnan swami :

When an acharya was giving upanyasam several hundred years back in srirangam, a layman in audience starting scolding the acharya in front of everyone. Once he was done, the acharya called the layman up to the stage and gave him his shawl/money and thanked him. When shishyas asked why, he replied *'Everyday I have 2 duties - Praise the qualities of Bhagavan. And Blame my own insufficiency. All these days, I only had time for the former, but neglected the latter. This man helped me in doing my duty, so I showed my gratitude to him'.*